# How do I make my site compatible with Firefox's Reader View feature

Tags: firefox, markup, articles

The latest version of Firefox has a button called "Reader View" that is supposed to hide the clutter on the page such as sidebars and headers and only show the article.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages

How do I make my site compatible with this button?    When I click the button on my site it says:

> Failed to load article from page

Comment: Well, it's very much still in development and its buggy, for example this page doesn't work on reader view yet others on ProWebmasters does. Only thing I'd say is make sure your using the vary latest Firefox.

Comment: On Stack Overflow: [How Does Firefox Reader View Operate (FF version 38.0.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30661650/1591669) ··· [Optimize website to show reader view in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30730300/1591669)

Comment: Related issue on Mozilla’s Readability GitHub: [Stack Exchange pages seem to show only the question or one answer in Reader View](https://github.com/mozilla/readability/issues/232)

Answer (score 7):

- Firefox's readerview
- Microsoft's Read later thing
- Chrome's Readability
- Evernote's Clearly
- Safari's Reading List

All of these have one thing in common.. they need text and they need properly formed HTML code behind them.

Having these two things in your website will not only make them work with these new features but will also give you the benefit of meeting more SEO requirements for better placement in the search engines.

Comment: I can confirm that malformed HTML can cause the readerview to not appear.

Comment: Is a markup validation service that can check whether a page is displaying "malformed HTML" currently available? I mean malformed in the screen reader context.

Comment: @IGP is the good old [W3C markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/) enough for you?

Answer (score 6):

Check source code for Firefox:

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/reader/Readability.js

```
 * grabArticle - Using a variety of metrics (content score, classname, element types), find the content that is
 *         most likely to be the stuff a user wants to read. Then return it wrapped up in a div.
```

You can find lots of comment like:

> Remove DIV, SECTION, and HEADER nodes without any content(e.g. text, image, video, or iframe).

> Loop through all paragraphs, and assign a score to them based on how content-y they look.

> Add a point for the paragraph itself as a base.

> Add points for any commas within this paragraph.

> For every 100 characters in this paragraph, add another point. Up to 3 points.

> After we've calculated scores, loop through all of the possible
> candidate nodes we found and find the one with the highest score.

> Scale the final candidates score based on link density. Good content
> should have a relatively small link density (5% or less) and be mostly
> unaffected by this operation.

Good summary is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747529/173149

Comment: This code is on GitHub too now: https://github.com/mozilla/readability/blob/master/Readability.js

Answer (score 3):

[Have a `<p>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30750306/327074) amazingly seems to be quite critical. For example this [History of Mathematics page on Abu Kamil](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Abu_Kamil/) has very well formatted HTML but is still not enough. The critical problem appears to be because it lists no `<p>` tags but instead puts its base text inside `<span class="markup">`.

If you look in the source of the page it has:

1. Properly formatted HTML 5
2. It uses `<header>` and `<main>` sections
3. Has lots of relevant non-spammy text on the page
4. Uses proper headings
5. Displays nicely if you force it into Reader View `about:reader?url=https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Abu_Kamil/`

But as per [@gavenkoa's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/135977/7548) (emphasis mine):

> - Loop through all **paragraphs**, and assign a score to them based on how content-y they look.
> - Add a point for the **paragraph** itself as a base.
> - Add points for any commas within this **paragraph**.
> - For every 100 characters in this **paragraph**, add another point. Up to 3 points.

No Paragraphs No Glory

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no official documentation about this, see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1067528. However, I'd advise trying wrapping your article in `<article>` tag.