# How can I ensure Chromium Edge's Immersive Reader is available on my pages?

Tags: html

[Immersive Reader](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/use-learning-tools-in-the-edge-browser-78a7a17d-52e1-47ee-b0ac-eff8539015e1) seems to be quite picky about the pages on which it will enable the address bar button. While there is always the option to select a block of text and right-click to open it in the reader, we would like to know if it's possible to structure our content pages in a way that ensures it is always available?

As a note, I am aware other browsers (FF, Chrome, etc) have similar modes and I would like to support those as well, but Immersive Reader in particular has language understanding tools which I expect will make it particularly appealing for educators. That is the market we serve so Immersive Reader is my focus.

Comment: See also: [How do I make my site compatible with Firefox's Reader View feature](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83058/how-do-i-make-my-site-compatible-with-firefoxs-reader-view-feature)